# Google Tag Manager Consent Mode & Analytics do not apply consent refusal in a React SPA

Tags: reactjs, cookies, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I have a React SPA and I implemented a cookie banner with CookieYes in order to inform the user that Google Analytics will be used if he gives his consent.

I followed the tutorials given by CookieYes to implement everything through Google Manager including this page https://www.cookieyes.com/documentation/block-third-party-cookies-with-google-tag-manager-and-cookieyes/

Here's my config in GTM :

[image]

I have set the default consent to *denied* and it works perfectly. Google Analytics only triggers when the value of the CookieYes cookie contains *analytics:yes*.

The problem is when the user denies the cookies permission afterwards : it doesn't change anything ! I can see in GTM debug view that the consent is set to denied but Analytics keeps tracking the user. **I have to refresh** the page in order to make Analytics stop the tracking.

That's why I added an exception to the Analytics tag but it doesn't have any effect. Even though the trigger should block the tracking if cookieYes contains *analytics:no* , Analytics keeps the tracking (I have checked the value of the cookie and it contains *analytics:no* )

So I'd like to know why I do have to refresh the page when a user denies the cookies whereas when he accepts, it automatically trigger analytics and why my exception doesn't work ?

Did someone face the same problem and find a solution ?

Thanks for your help